# Configure Visual Studio Code to run Python in bash on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run python `.py` file in Visual Studio Code using Windows bash console.

What I tried to do:

Change default shell in `settings.json`:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
}
```

Add task in `tasks.json` to run `python` command with file name as an argument:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Run python in bash",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": ["${file}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

There are a few problems to solve here:

1. Tasks are not being run in bash as I wanted
2. To access `C` drive [I need to replace](http://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/) `C:\` with `/mnt/c` in file path

Can you share with my solutions to those problems?

Comment: +1, i also need to use my windows python files to compile using bash in windows, do share the solution if one have

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't managed to automate this thing. Running python in Windows Bash is for now not a good idea.

Comment: okay , i have asked vscode team about this solution, i will update if they respond in positive :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 10 with `bash` but I'd imagine the problem is that you're not actually trying to run Python.  You're trying to run `bash` (and then run `python`).  Try setting the command to `bash` with params `["python", "$file"]`.

Comment: This is what I see trying that: "'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of this extension and haven't looked into this as of yet. There's an issue in github. Will look into this sometime in the near future. In the mean time I found a link that might be of use: https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/139

Comment: Sounds like you need to include the full path to bash rather than just "bash".